# jqGrid with filterToolbar hangs on searching for "\" character

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using a jqGrid with a filterToolbar and though I have been able to search for nearly all special characters, it looks like when you put in '\' (backslash) character, the 'Loading..' sign comes up and then no operations are subsequently possible.

The same behavior seems to be showing @ http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html. Go to "New in version 3.7" > "Toolbar Search" and try putting a '\' in the search toolbar and you'll see the same problem.

Is there a way to at least not hang the grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example helps to find many small bugs in different parts of jqGrid. So +1 to your reputation from me. After fixing [the example1](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/BackslashFilter.htm) and [the example2](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/BackslashFilter1.htm), which I prepared to demonstrate the problem, work without any problem.

I will try to post today or tomorrow the bug (with the fixes) which I found in [the trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/). Short information for you: I made small fixes in grid.custom.js, grid.base.js, jquery.searchFilter.js and grid.formedit.js (see *-fixed.js files in the demo). The main fix in the grid.custom.js: the lines 575, 642

```
ruleGroup += "\"data\":\"" + n + "\"}";
```

should be replaced to

```
ruleGroup += "\"data\":\"" + n.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\').replace(/\"/g,'\\"') + "\"}";
```

and in grid.base.js the line 203

```
phrase=phrase.toString().replace(new RegExp('\\"',"g"),'\\"');
```

should be replaced to

```
phrase=phrase.toString().replace(/\\/g,'\\\\').replace(/\"/g,'\\"');
```

The fixes in jquery.searchFilter.js and grid.formedit.js are needed in the case if one combine "multisearch-style" data filtering (`filterToolbar` with the option `stringResult: true`) with the [single field searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching).

**UPDATED:** like I promised before I just posted the bug report with all my fixes [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/toolbar-filtering-or-searching-for-strings-contains-backslashes-or-double-quotes/#p21813). I hope that Tony (the developer of jqGrid) will read it and include the fixes in the next version of jqGrid.